# Missing .NET Framework 4.0 in Visual Studio 2017 Prerequisites when publishing

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, publish

[image: As you can see, .NET Framework 4.0 is missing]

Hello, I need to publish my application with .NET Framework 4.0 (for windows XP support) but when trying to add it to the prerequisites it is missing. What can i do?

Comment: Support for .NET 4.0, 4.5 and 4.5.1 was discontinued in January 2016.  So expecting Microsoft to still provide you with the bootstrapper is idle hope.  The kind of users that *need* v4.0, XP and Win2003 users, have to take care of their own machine.  If you *must* provide them with support then consider to use an old VS version, they are available through an MSDN subscription.

Comment: oh ok thank you, makes sense

Answer (score 14, accepted):

i used the old, free "Bootstrap Manifest Generator" tool, which is a bit hard to find nowadays. My steps were as follows:

1. I downloaded the .NET Framework 4.0 redistributable package: https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17718
2. To get the package to appear in the "Prerequisites" dialog box, i downloaded the "Bootstrap Manifest Generator" tool from SoftPedia (http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Bootstrapper-Manifest-Generator.shtml). I scanned my download with McAfee and it was safe.
3. I installed the package and ran it. The series of images below illustrate the options that i selected on the tool:

Select "New Project" and then the "Package Manifest" option
[image: Select "New Project" and then the "Package Manifest" option]
- Fill-in the Project Name and Project Code, and then click the first icon above the white panel labeled "Package"
- Browse to the redistributable package
[image]

Enter the "Display Name" and then click the second icon above the white panel. The output folder will be highlighted in blue.
[image]

Move the containing folder (navigate one level up to copy the "*DotNETFX40*" folder) to the location shown below (Note, i'm using VS2017 Community on Windows 10):
[image]

In my WPF application, in the "Prerequisites" dialog, i now see the DotNETFX40 folder, as highlighted below. 
[image]

Now when i publish the application, the DotNETFX40 folder is published as well:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! I can't upvote this answer enough.

Comment: Hey @arlvin, is there a way to rename the "DotNETFX40" to a proper name like "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0" or something similar. Just to follow the names of other frameworks? Does renaming the folder work or I can keep the folder name as it is and change the display name somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

I think you will have to use Visual Studio **2015** to be able to select .NET Framework 4.0 as a prerequisite.

The official support for .NET Framework 4 has ended: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/